# In which cases do I need to create two different extension methods for IEnumerable and IQueryable?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, ienumerable, iqueryable

Let's say I need an extension method which selects only required properties from different sources. The source could be the database or in-memory collection. So I have defined such extension method:

```
 public IQueryable<TResult> SelectDynamic<TResult>(
            this IQueryable<T> source,
            ...)
```

This works fine for `IQueryable`s. But, I have to call this function also for `IEnumerable`s.

And in that case, I can call it with the help of `.AsQueryable()`:

```
  myEnumerable.AsQueryable()
        .SelectDynamic(...)
        .ToList();
```

Both work fine. And if both work fine, **in which conditions** I have to create two different extension methods for the same purpose, one for `IEnumerable` and another one for `IQueryable`?

My method has to send query to the database in case of `Queryable`.

For example, here is the source of `.Select`  extension method inside `System.Linq` namespace:

- [`.Select` for IEnumerable](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,5c652c53e80df013)
- [`.Select` for IQueryable](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/IQueryable.cs,017f3b205593b416)

*I am repeating my main question again:*

My method must send query to the database in case of `Queryable`, but not when working with `IEnumerable`. And for now, I am using `AsQueryable()` for the enumerables. Because, I dont want to write same code for the `Enumerable`. **Can it have some side effects?**

Comment: Actually, I think this is a good question because nobody seems to know what AsQueryable really does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`myEnumerable.AsQueryable()` returns a custom object: `new EnumerableQuery<TElement>(myEnumerable);` ([source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/SequenceQuery.cs,faf63cececc89018,references))

This `EnumerableQuery` class implements `IEnumerable<T>` and `IQueryable<T>`

When using the `EnumerableQuery` result of `.AsQueryable()` as an `IEnumerable`, the implementation of the interface method `IEnumerable<T>.GetIterator()` simply returns the original source iterator, so no change and minimal overhead.

When using the result of `.AsQueryable()` as an `IQueriable`, the implementation of the interface property `IQueriable.Expression` simply returns `Expression.Constant(this)`, ready to be evaluated later  as an IEnumerable when the whole expression tree is consumed.

(All the other methods and code paths of `EnumerableQuery` are not really relevant, when the EnumerableQuery is constructed directly from an IEnumerable, as far as I can tell)

If I understand you correctly, you have implemented your method `selectDynamic<TResult>()` in such a way that you construct an expression tree inside the method, that produces the desired result when compiled.

As far as I understand the source code, when you call e.g. `myEnumerable.AsEnumerable().selectDynamic().ToList()`, the expression tree you constructed is compiled and executed on myEnumerable, and the total overhead should be fairly minimal, since all this work is only done once per query, not once per element.

So i think there is nothing wrong with implementing your IEnumerable Extension method like this:

```
public IEnumerable<TResult> SelectDynamic<TResult>(
        this IEnumerable<T> source,...)
    return source.AsQueryable().SelectDynamic();
}
```

There is some slight overhead, since this compiles the query once each time this method is called, and I am not sure the JITer is smart enough to cache this compilation. But I think that will not be noticeable in most circumstances, unless you execute this query a thousand times per second.

There should be no other side efects, apart from slight performance issues, in implementing the IEnumerable extension method in this way.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am marking this as an answer. This sentence made me to understand the process better:

**There is some slight overhead, since this compiles the query once each time this method is called, and I am not sure the JITer is smart enough to cache this compilation.**

Answer (score 5):

If your code only actually works when the objects its dealing with are loaded in memory, just supply the `IEnumerable` variant and let your *callers* decide when they want to convert an `IQueryable` into an in-memory `IEnumerable`.

Generally, you won't implement new variations around `IQueryable` unless you're writing a new database provider.

Comment: I had a half (badly) written answer along the same lines - if you're writing `IQueryable` extensions, you need to try to ensure you treat it as an `IQueryable` throughout and not actually cause the query to be resolved in your code

Comment: My method must send query to the database in case of `Queryable`, but not when working with `IEnumerable`. And for now, I am using `AsQueryable` for the ernumerables. Because, i dont want to write same code for the enumerables. Can it have some side effects?