# Transform an expression tree taking IQueryable<T> into one taking IEnumerable<T>

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, expression-trees, dynamic-language-runtime

I have an `Expression<Func<IQueryable<TIn>,TOut>>`, and I'd like to transform it into `Expression<Func<IEnumerable<TIn>,TOut>>`. Actually, my end goal is to compile the given tree into `Func<IEnumerable<TIn>,TOut>>`, but that is trivial once the transformation is done.

I could just wrap the given lambda into one that first calls `AsQueryable()` on the input sequence, but I assume this is highly inefficient. I assume it would have to traverse the expression tree and compile it every time it's used.

Any ideas?

EDIT:

Of course, certain assumptions have to be made. The transformation should only know how to transform exact matches of static methods from `Queryable` to equivalent static methods from `Enumerable`. Otherwise it should either fail or even just do whatever. I don't really care.

EDIT 2:

Some more clarifications:

The input to the process I want to make takes a lambda expression tree. That lambda takes an `IQueryable<T>` as input and produces some output. I want to produce a new lambda with equivalent logic, but that takes an `IEnumerable<T>` as input and produces the equivalent output.

For instance, all calls to `Queryable.Where(...)` should be replaced by calls to `Enumerable.Where(...)`, `Queryable.Select(...)` with `Enumerable.Select(...)` etc.

EDIT 3:

An example:

```
// The expression I get transforms IQueryables, for instance this one:
Expression<Func<IQueryable<int>, double>> input =
    qi => (double)qi.Sum() / qi.Count();

// I want an expression that transforms IEnumerables:
Expression<Func<IEnumerable<int>, double>> desiredOutput =
    ei => (double)ei.Sum() / ei.Count();

// I can make it work like this:
var dirtyWorkaround = MakeDirtyWorkaround(input);

Expression<Func<IEnumerable<TIn>, TOut>> MakeDirtyWorkaround<TIn, TOut>(
    Expression<Func<IQueryable<TIn>, TOut>> original)
{
    // Doing this:
    //   ei => original.Invoke(ei.AsQueryable())

    var asQueryableMethod = new Func<IEnumerable<TIn>, IQueryable<TIn>>(Queryable.AsQueryable).Method;

    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(IEnumerable<TIn>), "ie");

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<IEnumerable<TIn>, TOut>>(
        Expression.Invoke(original,
            Expression.Call(asQueryableMethod, parameter)),
        parameter);
}

// But it's inefficient. Demonstration:

// The compiled expression can be cached.
var compiledDesired = desiredOutput.Compile();
var compiledDirty = dirtyWorkaround.Compile();

var exampleEnumerable = Enumerable.Range(1, 10);
var repetitions = 10_000;

// Desired test:
var desiredSw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
for (var i = 0; i < repetitions; ++i)
{
    var exampleOutput = compiledDesired.Invoke(exampleEnumerable);
}
desiredSw.Stop();

// Dirty test:
var dirtySw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
for (var i = 0; i < repetitions; ++i)
{
    // For every loop iteration, a query gets built on top of exampleEnumerable,
    // then gets adapted to IEnumerable and compiled.
    // It's ~1000 times slower in this case.
    var exampleOutput = compiledDirty.Invoke(exampleEnumerable);
}
dirtySw.Stop();

Console.WriteLine($"Executed in {dirtySw.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms instead of {desiredSw.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms.");
// Executed in 3000 ms instead of 3 ms.
```

Comment: Those are *very* different beasts. An IQueryable represents a *query* while IEnumerable represents the results of executing that query. You can't convert a query into its results. You have to execute it and apply the expression to the results

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Then how does `Queryable.AsQueryable()` work? Surely it does something similar, if not the exact same thing, once you actually enumerate a query resulting from chaining a bunch of transformations.

Comment: That method applies to *IEnumerable* and creates a query on top of the already availavble results. You're asking to "convert" a query to its results. The only way to do that is to execute the query

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30909228/in-which-cases-do-i-need-to-create-two-different-extension-methods-for-ienumerab -  Just might be help a bit

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes. And the resulting IQueryable just contains an expression tree that needs to be executed on the original IEnumerable when you call GetEnumerator(). That's almost exactly what I want to do, but I want to precompile it.

Comment: You can just cast IQueryable<T> to IEnumerable<T> but that will change the behavior of the entire expression. IQueryable expressions become part of the entire query. They don't run themselves, a provider executes the overall query eg by translating it to SQL or another language, or calling some other API. On the other hand, with IEnumerable the expressions themselves will execute and filter or modify the input source

Comment: `but I want to precompile it` that's a *completely* different question than what you asked. You don't do that by converting to IEnumerable. In fact, there have been similar libraries in the past, that transform, simplify and speed up LINQ to Objects queries. What you call `transform` is a complex operation that's specific to the operators, if not the overall query.

Comment: Found it: [LinqOptimizer](https://github.com/palladin/LinqOptimizer)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos `that's a completely different question than what you asked` I stated exactly this in the first paragraph of the question. And I never said I want to convert something to an IEnumerable. I said I want to transform a tree taking IQueryable into an equivalent one taking IEnumerable. Thanks for the link, I'll look into it.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos That library optimizes IEnumerable queries (in other words, calls to Enumerable static methods). Github search doesn't find any mention of Queryable or IQueryable so it can't possibly do what I asked about. Please understand what the question is even about before starting these discussions.

Comment: @relatively_random I do understand, which is why I point out the discrepancies and contradictions in the question. It's also why I can think of similar work by [Jon Skeet](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2007/10/03/linq-to-silliness-generating-a-mandelbrot-with-parallel-potential/), Nick Palladinos and his team, like [GpuLinq](https://github.com/nessos/GpuLinq). Do check those repositories, as they use the techniques *you* need to manipulate expressions.

Comment: @relatively_random on the other hand, it's LINQ to Objects' job to take an IQueryable and apply it to an IEnumerable. Calls to `Queryable.Where` *are* replaced by calls to `Enumerable.Where` already. Can you post an actual example of what you want to do? When people talk about precompiled LINQ or Enumerable queries, they *don't* mean just executing or applying the query

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos `it's LINQ to Objects' job to take an IQueryable and apply it to an IEnumerable. Calls to Queryable.Where are replaced by calls to Enumerable.Where already` Like I said in the second paragraph, it's inefficient. If you have a `Func<IEnumerable<T>,TOut>` that just calls `.AsQueryable()` and then applies queryable transformations, you're building an expression tree describing those transformations every time you call the `Func`. Then that new expression tree needs to be transformed and compiled each time. I want to do those steps up-front. I'll look at the links, thanks.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Again, not what I was looking for. I added an example to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Given that `.AsQueryable()` does *almost* what I want, I took a look at its code on GitHub. It generates an `EnumerableQuery` class. Looking up what the class does once the query is executed, I got to [EnumerableRewriter.cs](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Linq.Queryable/src/System/Linq/EnumerableRewriter.cs), which does the tricky expression tree transformation I'm interested in.

I hacked the class to transform `IQueryable<T>` parameters instead of `EnumerableQuery` constants. There's probably wrinkles left to smooth out, but it's a great start.

```
// Licensed to the .NET Foundation under one or more agreements.
// The .NET Foundation licenses this file to you under the MIT license.
// See the LICENSE file in the project root for more information.

using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Reflection;

namespace Test
{
    internal class EnumerableRewriter : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        public ReadOnlyDictionary<ParameterExpression, ParameterExpression> GetParameterReplacements()
            => parameterReplacements == null
                ? null
                : new ReadOnlyDictionary<ParameterExpression, ParameterExpression>(parameterReplacements);

        private Dictionary<ParameterExpression, ParameterExpression> parameterReplacements;
        protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression par)
        {
            var type = par.Type;
            if (type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IQueryable<>))
            {
                if (parameterReplacements == null)
                    parameterReplacements = new Dictionary<ParameterExpression, ParameterExpression>();

                if (!parameterReplacements.TryGetValue(par, out var replacement))
                {
                    var elementType = type.GetGenericArguments()[0];
                    replacement = Expression.Parameter(
                        typeof(IEnumerable<>).MakeGenericType(elementType),
                        par.Name);
                    parameterReplacements[par] = replacement;
                }

                return replacement;
            }
            return par;
        }

        // We must ensure that if a LabelTarget is rewritten that it is always rewritten to the same new target
        // or otherwise expressions using it won't match correctly.
        private Dictionary<LabelTarget, LabelTarget> _targetCache;
        // Finding equivalent types can be relatively expensive, and hitting with the same types repeatedly is quite likely.
        private Dictionary<Type, Type> _equivalentTypeCache;

        protected override Expression VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression m)
        {
            var obj = Visit(m.Object);
            var args = Visit(m.Arguments);

            // check for args changed
            if (obj != m.Object || args != m.Arguments)
            {
                var mInfo = m.Method;
                var typeArgs = (mInfo.IsGenericMethod) ? mInfo.GetGenericArguments() : null;

                if ((mInfo.IsStatic || mInfo.DeclaringType.IsAssignableFrom(obj.Type))
                    && ArgsMatch(mInfo, args, typeArgs))
                {
                    // current method is still valid
                    return Expression.Call(obj, mInfo, args);
                }
                else if (mInfo.DeclaringType == typeof(Queryable))
                {
                    // convert Queryable method to Enumerable method
                    var seqMethod = FindEnumerableMethod(mInfo.Name, args, typeArgs);
                    args = FixupQuotedArgs(seqMethod, args);
                    return Expression.Call(obj, seqMethod, args);
                }
                else
                {
                    // rebind to new method
                    var method = FindMethod(mInfo.DeclaringType, mInfo.Name, args, typeArgs);
                    args = FixupQuotedArgs(method, args);
                    return Expression.Call(obj, method, args);
                }
            }
            return m;
        }

        private ReadOnlyCollection<Expression> FixupQuotedArgs(MethodInfo mi, ReadOnlyCollection<Expression> argList)
        {
            var pis = mi.GetParameters();
            if (pis.Length > 0)
            {
                List<Expression> newArgs = null;
                for (int i = 0, n = pis.Length; i < n; i++)
                {
                    var arg = argList[i];
                    var pi = pis[i];
                    arg = FixupQuotedExpression(pi.ParameterType, arg);
                    if (newArgs == null && arg != argList[i])
                    {
                        newArgs = new List<Expression>(argList.Count);
                        for (var j = 0; j < i; j++)
                        {
                            newArgs.Add(argList[j]);
                        }
                    }

                    newArgs?.Add(arg);
                }
                if (newArgs != null)
                    argList = newArgs.AsReadOnly();
            }
            return argList;
        }

        private Expression FixupQuotedExpression(Type type, Expression expression)
        {
            var expr = expression;
            while (true)
            {
                if (type.IsAssignableFrom(expr.Type))
                    return expr;
                if (expr.NodeType != ExpressionType.Quote)
                    break;
                expr = ((UnaryExpression)expr).Operand;
            }
            if (!type.IsAssignableFrom(expr.Type) && type.IsArray && expr.NodeType == ExpressionType.NewArrayInit)
            {
                var strippedType = StripExpression(expr.Type);
                if (type.IsAssignableFrom(strippedType))
                {
                    var elementType = type.GetElementType();
                    var na = (NewArrayExpression)expr;
                    var exprs = new List<Expression>(na.Expressions.Count);
                    for (int i = 0, n = na.Expressions.Count; i < n; i++)
                    {
                        exprs.Add(FixupQuotedExpression(elementType, na.Expressions[i]));
                    }
                    expression = Expression.NewArrayInit(elementType, exprs);
                }
            }
            return expression;
        }

        protected override Expression VisitLambda<T>(Expression<T> node) => node;

        private static Type GetPublicType(Type t)
        {
            // If we create a constant explicitly typed to be a private nested type,
            // such as Lookup<,>.Grouping or a compiler-generated iterator class, then
            // we cannot use the expression tree in a context which has only execution
            // permissions.  We should endeavour to translate constants into
            // new constants which have public types.
            if (t.IsGenericType && t.GetGenericTypeDefinition().GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(IGrouping<,>)))
                return typeof(IGrouping<,>).MakeGenericType(t.GetGenericArguments());
            if (!t.IsNestedPrivate)
                return t;
            foreach (var iType in t.GetInterfaces())
            {
                if (iType.IsGenericType && iType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEnumerable<>))
                    return iType;
            }
            if (typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(t))
                return typeof(IEnumerable);
            return t;
        }

        private Type GetEquivalentType(Type type)
        {
            if (_equivalentTypeCache == null)
            {
                // Pre-loading with the non-generic IQueryable and IEnumerable not only covers this case
                // without any reflection-based introspection, but also means the slightly different
                // code needed to catch this case can be omitted safely.
                _equivalentTypeCache = new Dictionary<Type, Type>
                        {
                            { typeof(IQueryable), typeof(IEnumerable) },
                            { typeof(IEnumerable), typeof(IEnumerable) }
                        };
            }
            if (!_equivalentTypeCache.TryGetValue(type, out var equiv))
            {
                var pubType = GetPublicType(type);
                if (pubType.IsInterface && pubType.IsGenericType)
                {
                    var genericType = pubType.GetGenericTypeDefinition();
                    if (genericType == typeof(IOrderedEnumerable<>))
                        equiv = pubType;
                    else if (genericType == typeof(IOrderedQueryable<>))
                        equiv = typeof(IOrderedEnumerable<>).MakeGenericType(pubType.GenericTypeArguments[0]);
                    else if (genericType == typeof(IEnumerable<>))
                        equiv = pubType;
                    else if (genericType == typeof(IQueryable<>))
                        equiv = typeof(IEnumerable<>).MakeGenericType(pubType.GenericTypeArguments[0]);
                }
                if (equiv == null)
                {
                    var interfacesWithInfo = pubType.GetInterfaces().Select(IntrospectionExtensions.GetTypeInfo).ToArray();
                    var singleTypeGenInterfacesWithGetType = interfacesWithInfo
                        .Where(i => i.IsGenericType && i.GenericTypeArguments.Length == 1)
                        .Select(i => new { Info = i, GenType = i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() })
                        .ToArray();
                    var typeArg = singleTypeGenInterfacesWithGetType
                        .Where(i => i.GenType == typeof(IOrderedQueryable<>) || i.GenType == typeof(IOrderedEnumerable<>))
                        .Select(i => i.Info.GenericTypeArguments[0])
                        .Distinct()
                        .SingleOrDefault();
                    if (typeArg != null)
                        equiv = typeof(IOrderedEnumerable<>).MakeGenericType(typeArg);
                    else
                    {
                        typeArg = singleTypeGenInterfacesWithGetType
                            .Where(i => i.GenType == typeof(IQueryable<>) || i.GenType == typeof(IEnumerable<>))
                            .Select(i => i.Info.GenericTypeArguments[0])
                            .Distinct()
                            .Single();
                        equiv = typeof(IEnumerable<>).MakeGenericType(typeArg);
                    }
                }
                _equivalentTypeCache.Add(type, equiv);
            }
            return equiv;
        }



        private static ILookup<string, MethodInfo> s_seqMethods;
        private static MethodInfo FindEnumerableMethod(string name, ReadOnlyCollection<Expression> args, params Type[] typeArgs)
        {
            if (s_seqMethods == null)
            {
                s_seqMethods = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
                                                 .ToLookup(m => m.Name);
            }
            var mi = s_seqMethods[name].FirstOrDefault(m => ArgsMatch(m, args, typeArgs));
            Debug.Assert(mi != null, "All static methods with arguments on Queryable have equivalents on Enumerable.");
            if (typeArgs != null)
                return mi.MakeGenericMethod(typeArgs);
            return mi;
        }

        private static MethodInfo FindMethod(Type type, string name, ReadOnlyCollection<Expression> args, Type[] typeArgs)
        {
            using (var en = type.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
                                .Where(m => m.Name == name)
                                .GetEnumerator())
            {
                if (!en.MoveNext())
                    throw new InvalidOperationException($"No method '{name}' on type '{type.FullName}'.");
                do
                {
                    var mi = en.Current;
                    if (ArgsMatch(mi, args, typeArgs))
                        return (typeArgs != null) ? mi.MakeGenericMethod(typeArgs) : mi;
                } while (en.MoveNext());
            }
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"No method '{name}{(typeArgs != null ? "<" + typeArgs + ">" : null)}' on type '{type.FullName}' matches arguments '{args}'.");
        }

        private static bool ArgsMatch(MethodInfo m, ReadOnlyCollection<Expression> args, Type[] typeArgs)
        {
            var mParams = m.GetParameters();
            if (mParams.Length != args.Count)
                return false;
            if (!m.IsGenericMethod && typeArgs != null && typeArgs.Length > 0)
            {
                return false;
            }
            if (!m.IsGenericMethodDefinition && m.IsGenericMethod && m.ContainsGenericParameters)
            {
                m = m.GetGenericMethodDefinition();
            }
            if (m.IsGenericMethodDefinition)
            {
                if (typeArgs == null || typeArgs.Length == 0)
                    return false;
                if (m.GetGenericArguments().Length != typeArgs.Length)
                    return false;
                m = m.MakeGenericMethod(typeArgs);
                mParams = m.GetParameters();
            }
            for (int i = 0, n = args.Count; i < n; i++)
            {
                var parameterType = mParams[i].ParameterType;
                if (parameterType == null)
                    return false;
                if (parameterType.IsByRef)
                    parameterType = parameterType.GetElementType();
                var arg = args[i];
                if (!parameterType.IsAssignableFrom(arg.Type))
                {
                    if (arg.NodeType == ExpressionType.Quote)
                    {
                        arg = ((UnaryExpression)arg).Operand;
                    }
                    if (!parameterType.IsAssignableFrom(arg.Type) &&
                        !parameterType.IsAssignableFrom(StripExpression(arg.Type)))
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
            return true;
        }

        private static Type StripExpression(Type type)
        {
            var isArray = type.IsArray;
            var tmp = isArray ? type.GetElementType() : type;
            var eType = GetExpressionType(tmp);
            if (eType != null)
                tmp = eType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
            if (isArray)
            {
                var rank = type.GetArrayRank();
                return (rank == 1) ? tmp.MakeArrayType() : tmp.MakeArrayType(rank);
            }
            return type;
        }

        private static Type GetExpressionType(Type type)
        {
            while (type != null && type != typeof(object))
            {
                if (type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Expression<>))
                    return type;
                type = type.BaseType;
            }
            return null;
        }

        protected override Expression VisitConditional(ConditionalExpression c)
        {
            var type = c.Type;
            if (!typeof(IQueryable).IsAssignableFrom(type))
                return base.VisitConditional(c);
            var test = Visit(c.Test);
            var ifTrue = Visit(c.IfTrue);
            var ifFalse = Visit(c.IfFalse);
            var trueType = ifTrue.Type;
            var falseType = ifFalse.Type;
            if (trueType.IsAssignableFrom(falseType))
                return Expression.Condition(test, ifTrue, ifFalse, trueType);
            if (falseType.IsAssignableFrom(trueType))
                return Expression.Condition(test, ifTrue, ifFalse, falseType);
            return Expression.Condition(test, ifTrue, ifFalse, GetEquivalentType(type));
        }

        protected override Expression VisitBlock(BlockExpression node)
        {
            var type = node.Type;
            if (!typeof(IQueryable).IsAssignableFrom(type))
                return base.VisitBlock(node);
            var nodes = Visit(node.Expressions);
            var variables = VisitAndConvert(node.Variables, "EnumerableRewriter.VisitBlock");
            if (type == node.Expressions.Last().Type)
                return Expression.Block(variables, nodes);
            return Expression.Block(GetEquivalentType(type), variables, nodes);
        }

        protected override Expression VisitGoto(GotoExpression node)
        {
            var type = node.Value.Type;
            if (!typeof(IQueryable).IsAssignableFrom(type))
                return base.VisitGoto(node);
            var target = VisitLabelTarget(node.Target);
            var value = Visit(node.Value);
            return Expression.MakeGoto(node.Kind, target, value, GetEquivalentType(typeof(EnumerableQuery).IsAssignableFrom(type) ? value.Type : type));
        }

        protected override LabelTarget VisitLabelTarget(LabelTarget node)
        {
            LabelTarget newTarget;
            if (_targetCache == null)
                _targetCache = new Dictionary<LabelTarget, LabelTarget>();
            else if (_targetCache.TryGetValue(node, out newTarget))
                return newTarget;
            var type = node.Type;
            if (!typeof(IQueryable).IsAssignableFrom(type))
                newTarget = base.VisitLabelTarget(node);
            else
                newTarget = Expression.Label(GetEquivalentType(type), node.Name);
            _targetCache.Add(node, newTarget);
            return newTarget;
        }
    }
}
```

Quick test:

```
// The expression I get transforms IQueryables, for instance this one:
Expression<Func<IQueryable<int>, double>> input =
    qi => (double)qi.Sum() / qi.Count();

// I want an expression that transforms IEnumerables:
Expression<Func<IEnumerable<int>, double>> desiredOutput =
    ei => (double)ei.Sum() / ei.Count();

var cleanSolution = MakeClean(input);

Expression<Func<IEnumerable<TIn>, TOut>> MakeClean<TIn, TOut>(
    Expression<Func<IQueryable<TIn>, TOut>> original)
{
    var rewriter = new EnumerableRewriter();
    var newBody = rewriter.Visit(original.Body);
    var replacements = rewriter.GetParameterReplacements();
    var newParams = original.Parameters.Select(p => replacements.TryGetValue(p, out var replacement) ? replacement : p);
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<IEnumerable<TIn>, TOut>>(newBody, newParams);
}

var compiledDesired = desiredOutput.Compile();
var compiledClean = cleanSolution.Compile();

var exampleEnumerable = Enumerable.Range(1, 10);
var repetitions = 10_000;

// Desired test:
var desiredSw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
for (var i = 0; i < repetitions; ++i)
{
    var exampleOutput = compiledDesired.Invoke(exampleEnumerable);
}
desiredSw.Stop();

// Clean test:
var cleanSw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
for (var i = 0; i < repetitions; ++i)
{
    var exampleOutput = compiledClean.Invoke(exampleEnumerable);
}
cleanSw.Stop();

Console.WriteLine($"Executed in {cleanSw.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms instead of {desiredSw.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms.");
// It now executes at roughly the same speed.
```